# Typescript, T extends T?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

could anyone explain what T extends T? specifically does? can't find any explanations anywhere on the internet, it seems like a ternary operator but it does a lot more, and why do my functions myFun and myFunt take different arguments although they have fundamentally the same type?

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends T? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, undefined>> : never;
export type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type A = { a: string, b: string };

type B = { c: string, d: string };

type C = { e: string, f: string };
type D = { a: string, b: string } & (|{ c: string, d: string } | { e: string, f: string })


// possible -> a | b | c | d | e | f

const myFun = (args: UnionKeys<D>) => {
    return args;
}

// possible args: a | b

const myFunt = (args: D extends D? keyof D : never) => {
    return args
}
```

Comment: It's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), and you are running into distributive conditional types which only happen when the type you check is a generic type parameter.

Comment: @jcalz I am sure that @tommy asks about what does it mean for a type to extend itself, and why would someone use a construct `value: T extends T ? T : never` instead of a simpler `value: T`

Comment: thank you very much!! i took a look at distributive conditional types and that solved the problem

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Indeed, `T extends T ? T : never` would be a do-nothing operation (though it might still have an effect on type inference, since conditional types are resolved later than other types). But `T extends T ? Something<T> : never` is not equivalent to `Something<T>` when `T` is a union, due to distributivity.